# Google map loading issue iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have integrated `GoogleMap` using pod in my project but map is not loading. When I make my mapViewController as a initial `ViewController` then its working fine.

But when I push or present MapViewController then its showing me the blank screen.

I am using `XCode 9.1`, my project deployment Target is `9.0` and `Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.5.30219.0`.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my MapViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.486726, 73.798394), zoom: 10)
        mapView.camera = camera
    }
}
```

Console Log:

> CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path
>
> /Users/pritamsing.salunkhe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6DD7C0EA-320F-4E99-BEC9-672046198800/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/04CC747F-5B2D-4588-883A-E814D4EE0769/HimmatPlus.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileVersionID.omo

[image: MapViewController when set as initial conrtroller]

[image: MapViewController when push from another ViewController]

Comment: what does the console log say ?

Comment: @Raptor updated the question with console log

Comment: @PritamSalunkhe did you solve this issue? I am also facing the same issue. Kindly guide me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use IBOutlet for googleMap in Storyboard & also Don't set subclass for GMSMapView.

implement your map by programmatically. Its will boost your Map UI faster

```
/// Google MapView
var mapView: GMSMapView!

self.mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: self.currentDeviceSize.width, height: self.bottomBgView.frame.minY - 64))
    // self.mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
self.mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = true
// self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true //Enable My location button
// self.mapView.isTrafficEnabled = true //Enable traffic
// self.mapView.isBuildingsEnabled = true // Building Enable
//  self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true //My location Enabled

// let containerView: GMSMapView = self.mapView
self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)
```

Comment: did this but still facing same issue

Comment: Did you use Location Manager update.?  & did you remove that outlet ? and remove SubClass setting in storyboard?

Comment: remove subclass of GMSMapView in storyboard. than implement above code

Comment: clean and run your project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162568/discussion-between-ktr-kathir-and-pritam-salunkhe).

Comment: Helo boss, why did you down voted?. my suggestion was working for me corretly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the proper implementation of Google map.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    self.configureMap()
}

func configureMap(){
    mapView.delegate = self
    //Check for Location Services
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

**MapView Delegate method**

```
//MARK:- MapView delegate
extension YourViewControllerName: GMSMapViewDelegate,   CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    //Location Manager delegates
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 12.0)
        self.mapView?.animate(to: camera)
        // To stop updating the location again 
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error description:\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

**Key In plist file.**

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your custom message.</string>
```